# django-pyodbc-azure is checking version on every request

Tags: django, django-pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/80

Every time a request is made, the `django-pyodbc-azure` backend is checking for the SQL version, resulting in a lot of additional latency:

```
QUERY = "SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS varchar)"
```

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to prevent it, or set the version ahead of time?